# Determine total data used by each client connected to android wifi hotspot

Tags: android, session, client, wifi

How can i determine that the devices that are connected to my wifi hotspot programmatically are consuming how much data in each session.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) class to get traffic statistics.

Comment: Yes, this is one way, but i want to determine this on android device which is being used as portable hotspot i.e. how much data is being consumed by the peers that are connected with this hotspot connection.